# I cannot display objects that are in an ArrayList in another package

Tags: java, arraylist, package

I am beginner, I try to solve an homework,
I have an java console project, I should create a package for each class, inside this package, it must have the Class model, an Interface, and a class who implements all method defined in the interface, that's mean each package will have total 3 classes.
now I have 2 packages,
the first contains : Room.java, IRoom.java, RoomT.java
the second package contains the Application class App.java
the problem is I have a menu in the Application class that can let me enter in a Room sub-menu or quit.
the Room sub-menu have :

1. save an room object in an ArrayList in RoomT.java
2. Display all object in the ArrayList.
3. back to main menu.

if I back to main menu I re-enter in room sub-menu, when I choose to display all object that I saved, the ArrayList is empty, I don't know why? how to solve that problem.
the classes is below;

**Room.java**

```
/**
 *
 * @author ******
 */
public class Room {
    private String id;
    private float price;
    
    public Room(){}
    public Room(String id, float price){
        this.id = id;
        this.price = price;
    }
    
    public String toString(){
    return " ID         :"+this.id+"\n"
           +" Price      : $"+this.price;
    }
}
```

**IRoom.java**

```
/**
 *
 * @author *******
 */
public interface IRoom {
    void save();
    void display();
}
```

**RoomT.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author *****
 */
public class RoomT implements IRoom{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner num = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    public ArrayList<Room> dbRoom = new ArrayList<>();
    Room room = new Room();
    
    public void save(){
        System.out.println("Id : ");
        String id = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Price : ");
        float price = num.nextFloat();
        room = new Room(id, price);
        dbRoom.add(room);
    }
    
    public void display(){
        if(dbRoom.isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("Room not saved yet!!!");
        }else{
            for(Room room: dbRoom){
                System.out.println("____________________________________________");
                System.out.println(room.toString());
                System.out.println("____________________________________________");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

App.java

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.hotel.app;
import com.hotel.room.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author *****
 */
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int choice;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        do{
            System.out.println("1. For Room Menu. ");
            System.out.println("0. For quitt programs.=. ");
            choice = input.nextInt();
            
            switch(choice){
                case 0 : 
                    System.exit(0);
                    break;
                case 1 :
                    Scanner num = new Scanner(System.in);
                    RoomT room = new RoomT();
                    int choicech;
                    do{
                        System.out.println("_______________ROOM MENU_________________________");
                        System.out.println(" 1. Save a room.");
                        System.out.println(" 2. Display all rooms.");
                        System.out.println(" 0. <-back to main menu.");
                        System.out.println("_____________________________________________________");

                        choicech = num.nextInt();

                        switch(choicech){
                            case 0 :
                                 choicech = 5;
                                 break;
                            case 1 : room.save();
                                break;
                            case 2 : room.display();
                                break;
                            default : System.out.println("Incorrect Choice!!!.");
                            break;
                        }

                    }while(choicech<3);
                    break;
                default : 
                    System.out.println("Incorrect!!");
                    break;
            }
        }while(choice<2);
    }
}
```

**The result**
[resultIMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2d4BP.png)

Comment: You need to show your Application class as well.

Comment: Ok, I just put the Application class.

Comment: You create a new `RoomT` instance each time you display the menu, so you lose the old one and the contents of its list of Rooms.

Comment: Thank you very much, thanks to you I can continue my project